# Функция exit() - завершает процесс?

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите пожалуйста, если в коде создано несколько процессов и в каждом процессе по несколько потоков, то при вызове функции exit() из любого процесса - завершит выполнение кода и очистить все ресурсы в том числе и "процессов" ?

Comment: `exit()` завершит только процесс (все его потоки) из которого она запущена

Comment: Потоки, созданные с помощью fork(), продолжат работать.

Comment: @64-coreCPU fork создает процессы